# dependency version is wrong

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, version

## 1:I have a parent project

it`s pom.xml below

```
...
  <modules>
    <module>first</module>
    <module>second</module>
  </modules>
  
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-alibaba-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

## 2:create first module

it's pom.xml below

```
...
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.ppf.demo</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>first</artifactId>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-seata</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.seata</groupId>
                    <artifactId>seata-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.seata</groupId>
            <artifactId>seata-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**I want Seata 1.2.0**.
because `spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-seata` has default Seata 1.1.0,so I exclude `seata-spring-boot-starter`  and `<dependency>` Seata 1.2.0 myself

[first module dependency -- Seata 1.2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls7N2.png)

## 3:create second module and has dependency first module

it's pom.xml below

```
...
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.ppf.demo</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>second</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ppf.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>first</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

## 4:Question

#### Why my second module is still has Seata 1.1.0,not 1.2.0

[second module dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIBsY.png)

Comment: The dependencies shown in an IDE are not the definitive way to see what dependencies you have. run `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Maven's rules about this subject are sometimes unclear and unhelpful, and your question may be a duplicate but is well asked.

Comment: @tgdavies `mvn dependency:tree`. results is same.

Comment: if you want replace some dependency version, you could try ```<properties>
    <seata-spring-boot-starter.version>1.2.0</seata-spring-boot-starter.version>
  </properties>```, Instead of exclude

Comment: thank you.I will try @袁文涛